# MongoDb trying to count inside embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, count, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

> I have a document which looks like this

```
{'name':'abc',
'location': 'xyz',
 'social_links' : { 'facebook' : 'links',
                     'stackoverflow': 'links',
                     'quora' : 'links' ... }
}
```

> I want to count the total number of links for each social_links in my collection
>   Currently my code looks like this

```
    db.main_candidate.aggregate( [  { '$match': {'social_links.quora':     {'$exists': true}}},  {'$group': { '_id' :'quora', 'count': {'$sum':1 }}}])
```

> While this is correctly returning the counts for the specific social_link, I want to write a query which will be able to count for all the social_links in a single query instead of having to write for each specific name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no way to group what you want with a query without hardcoding the specific names. Maybe you should try with MapReduce.

You should store social_links as an array instead as a document, which makes more sense to me. Something like:

```
{'name':'abc',
'location': 'xyz',
 'social_links' : [ { 'name':'facebook', 'link' : 'links'},
                    { 'name':'quora', 'link' : 'links'},
                    { 'name':'stackoverflow', 'link' : 'links'}]
}
```

Then you could do the following query:

```
db.col.aggregate(
{
 $unwind: "$social_links"
},
{
 $group: 
 {
   _id: "$social_links.name",
   count: $sum: 1
  }
})
```